# iTerm2 quake terminal focus lingering after pressing keyboard shortcut to toggle off

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

My workflow is working with one Quake-style iTerm2 terminal and more often than not works besides Chrome, googling, and whatnot. So my Quake-style terminal would be floating over Google Chrome and when I want to toggle off the Quake terminal, open up a new Chrome tab, and Google something it instead opens up a new tab on iTerm2 although I'm already toggled off. The focus is lingering after exiting and can keep the focus for up to 3 seconds before I can open up a new tab in Chrome.

It's rather frustrating and I haven't found a fix for it despite searching everywhere for a solution. Surely I can't be the only one with this problem.

[image: Animated .GIF of a Google Chrome tab open then a drop-down terminal window from iTerm2 opens for up to 3 seconds then closes]